# AWS hosting with HTTPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm working on this site that I'm hosting with AWS.  I'm hosting a vue.js frontend in an S3 bucket and the backend utilizes Spring Boot hosted with Elastic Beanstalk and a MySQL RDS instance.  After playing around some, I got the frontend to serve up files via HTTPS, but now my requests to the Spring API are failing.

I've done a lot of digging on this and it seems that are may be several ways to handle this, but I just keep getting stuck and not knowing where to turn next.  I've tried playing around with setting up a load balancer, and also tried configuring a proxy in a .ebextensions configuration file.

This whole thing was working when I set it up with HTTP originally, but now that the front-end is serving up HTTPS it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Web browsers must be blocking your mixed HTTP/HTTPs content because of their inbuilt security. You need to make sure that you setup the whole site using HTTPs or HTTP. As you have already set up the S3 content to be served through HTTPs, now you must configure your Elastic Beanstalk environment to be setup with HTTPs too. Here is the link to help you with that

[Configuring HTTPS for Your Elastic Beanstalk Environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html)

Comment: I attempted to work through tutorial in the link you posted, but I was running into connection issues still.  This link suggests setting up a load balancer, and I'm wondering if there's a better (and/or simpler) way to do this?  I'm also unsure what about my configuration was not working with the load balancer.

Comment: You need a load balancer to easily setup the HTTPs with AWS certificate manager. In my opinion, other methods can be more complicated.

Comment: Thank you!  My guess at this point then is that I'm either messing up ACM or that my health check is failing?

Comment: Is your HTTPs listener working? First make sure that it is working. Secondly you can hit the URL in the browesr and see if there is any SSL warning, expand the error to nail it further.

Comment: How can I check the HTTPS listener?

Comment: In your load balancer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202176/discussion-between-drew-kroft-and-juned-ahsan).

Answer (score 0):

If your site is built with a CRM? (WordPress/Joomla/ect.) then there are plugins/extensions that handle that. I had a similar situation with a WordPress site, and used the plug-in called "SSL Insecure Content Fixer". Worked without a hitch, rather than scanning through the entire site for mixed HTTP/HTTPs content.